# Javascript charAt() breaking multibyte character string

Tags: javascript, node.js, multibyte, encodeuricomponent, charat

This code breaks with nodejs v0.10.21

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var urlEncoded = 'http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%A8%A8%8F';
var urlDecoded = decodeURI( urlEncoded );
var urlLeafEncoded = urlEncoded.substr( 29 );
var urlLeafDecoded = decodeURIComponent( urlLeafEncoded );
var urlLeafFirstCharacterDecoded = urlLeafDecoded.charAt( 0 );
var urlLeafFirstCharacterEncoded = encodeURIComponent( urlLeafFirstCharacterDecoded );

console.log( 'URL encoded = ' + urlEncoded );
console.log( 'URL decoded = ' + urlDecoded );
console.log( 'URL leaf encoded = ' + urlLeafEncoded );
console.log( 'URL leaf decoded = ' + urlLeafDecoded );
console.log( 'URL leaf first character encoded = ' + urlLeafEncoded );
console.log( 'URL leaf first character decoded = ' + urlLeafDecoded );
```

I get the following error

```
var urlLeafFirstCharacterEncoded = encodeURIComponent( urlLeafFirstCharacterDe
                               ^
URIError: URI malformed
    at encodeURIComponent (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/data/tmp/mwoffliner/test.js:9:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Javascript used to deal correctly with multibyte characters, but not in that case. It seems that although "%F0%A8%A8%8F" represents one Chinese character, javascript believes they are two of them. I'm puzzled if this is a bug in javascript runtime, somehow an encoding issue, or a misunderstood on my side.

Comment: `var char = '';`, now `char.length === 2`, `char.charCodeAt(0) === 55394` and `char.charCodeAt(1) === 56847`, even though it is displayed as just a single character

Answer (score 5):

lies outside the BMP, and since Javascript only uses 2 bytes to store characters, is represented as a [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates). While `encodeURIComponent` can operate on surrogate pairs and produces the correct UTF8 encoding for them, it cannot read surrogates separately. Therefore, while `encodeURIComponent("")` works fine, `encodeURIComponent("".charAt(0))` will fail.

See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding for more details. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent documents this use case specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, this helps very much. Mozilla proposes a "fixed" version of string.charAt() which fix my problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt